# How to properly utilize while loop for password requirement

Tags: python

I am attempting to loop the string "Enter Password"
until the condition password == Hello is satisfied. However, currently this code will move onto the asking the user for 'name' regardless of what is entered in for password.

```
password = None

while password != 'Hello':
    print("Enter Password")
    password = input()

    if password == 'Hello':
        print("Access Granted, Welcome to second of the progam!")

    name = input("Please enter your name : ")

    if name == 'Jared':
        print("Wow, a truly spectaular name!")

    elif name == 'Madonna':
        print("May I have your autograph, please?")

    elif name == 'Cher':
        print("May I have your autograph, please?")

    else:
        print(name, ", That's a nice name.")
```

Comment: Regardless identation code should work fine, what exactly is wrong?

Comment: We can't know what's specifically wrong since your indentation got messed up when you posted this here. Running the code you posted will generate an IndentationError. Indentation is a fundamentally critical aspect of Python code.

Comment: Thank you for this correction. I have edited the code to reflect exactly what I have inside VS Code. 

I am currently executing changes based on Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not indent your if statements correctly. Also there is no need to check the password twice! If you run this it will work as desired :)

```
password = ''
name = ''

while password != 'hello':
    print("Enter Password")
    password = input()
else:
    print ("Access Granted, Welcome to second of the program!")
    name = input("Please enter your name : ")

    if name == 'Jared':
        print("Wow, a truly spectaular name!")

    elif name == 'Madonna':
        print("May I have your autograph, please?")

    elif name == 'Cher':
        print("May I have your autograph, please?")

    else:
        print(name, ", That's a nice name.")
```

*Hope this helps! :)*

Comment: If you found that this helps please consider marking this as accepted :)

Comment: Thank you, MegaByte. 

The format of this code makes complete sense. 
I was struggling to understand how to use multiple 'else' statements 
without causing a syntax error. 

I have tested this and it works perfectly. 
I'll me making a note of this syntax for future reference. 

much appreciated!

Comment: There's no need to use `while-else:`. The rest of the code can simply be after the `while` loop.

Comment: How do I mark this as accepted. Very new to this platform. I am astounded at how quickly the community responds to questions posted and want to contribute properly!

Comment: `else:` is generally only used if you need to distinguish ending the loop normally from ending with `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check if the password is correct twice (the `while` condition and the `if` statement). Use an infinite loop and then break out of it when the password is correct.

You can also put the password prompt as an argument to `input()`.

```
while True:
    password = input("Enter Password: ")

    if password == 'Hello':
        print("Access Granted, Welcome to second of the progam!")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect password, try again")
```

Comment: Thank you for offering your insight once again, Barmar. The speed of your responses are surprising and very much valued.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the condition in while loop if the password is 'hello' program will not execute.so the control of the program moves to next line of the loop. look into your while loop condition and change it according to your needs

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this issue, I appreciate your guidance.